# How to correct Discord API request giving error 1020

Tags: javascript, discord

i'm trying to make a request to discord api from my personal website, but it's giving the "Access denied Error code 1020", when I try using postMan it works.

Here's my code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  fetch('https://discord.com/api/v9/users/' + userId, {
    method: 'get',
    headers: new Headers({
      'Authorization': 'Bot ' + botToken,
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    })
  }).then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data))
};
```

and here's my response:

> Access denied Error code 1020
> You do not have access to discord.com.
>
> The site owner may have set restrictions that prevent you from accessing the site.
> Contact the site owner for access or try loading the page again.

Here's my Postman Request:
[image: postmanRequest]

Here's the cookie request:
[image: cookie request]

[image: cookie status]

Comment: 1) `GET` requests don't typically require a content-type header because there's no request body. 2) Have you double-checked the values of `userId` and `botToken`? Are you sure the `Authorization` header value should be prefixed with _"Bot"_. Is that what you're using in Postman?

Comment: Is this on Repl.it? Discord banned that IP address from accessing it.

Comment: @Phil 1) I'm using in Postman and works, but if i remove, nothing changes 2) Yes, the userID is Fine and botToken too, they're the same that I used in Postman 3) Yes, I'm using Prefixed "Bot + botToken" in Postman, the request in JS is the same that I used in postman

Comment: @Lisa No, I tried on LocalHost and deploying on Vercel, in both cases it doesn't work

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to show details / screenshots of how it works in Postman (redact your token of course). Also add `console.log("userId", JSON.stringify(userId)); console.log("botToken", JSON.stringify(botToken));` to make sure you've got the right values and there's no extra whitespace

Comment: @Phil Edited with postman Request and tried with JSON.stringify, but have the same error

Comment: I didn't say to _try_ `JSON.stringify()`, I said to use it in some console logging. It will wrap strings in quotes so you can see if they are exactly what you expect without leading or trailing whitespace

Comment: Why does your Postman request contain a `Cookie`?

Comment: @Phil I looked the console.log with `JSON.stringify()` and it's right, also I tried directly putting the URL and Authorization that I used in Postman and had the same error

Comment: @Phil When the request returns the Data, it creates the Cookie Key

Comment: Ok, sounds like your `botToken` is incorrect then. Compare the working and non-working requests in Postman to see what's different

Comment: @Phil As I said, I used the same as Postman, removing `botToken` var and putting directly   what i used in Postman, put had the same error 1020, the authorization request is like: `'Authorization': 'Bot ODIy` (the Token is complete in the code and don't have extra whitespace in final)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. What's interesting is that your Postman request has a **request cookie**. This is not the result of making that request since it exists before the request is even made. Try removing that cookie. Do you then get the same error?

Comment: @Phil When I removed the cookie and make the request, that cookie was automatically created and doesn't get any error

Comment: @Phil I added a printscreen with the cookie request that it automatically made by browser too